# Cannot read property 'name' of null on autocomplete material ui

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, frontend

i got a error when i click on the clear cross button of a autocomplete with material ui.
Here my AutoComplete:

```
               <Autocomplete
                autoComplete
                fullWidth
                options={esportTeams.list}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name ?? ""}
                className={classes.formControl}
                onChange={(e, value) => setFilter({ ...filter, team: value.name })}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} fullWidth label="Teams" 
                variant="outlined" value={filter.team ?? ""} size="small" />}
                />
```

When i click on the cross for clear the field i got this error : Cannot read property 'name' of null and i have test a lot of things but no one works ...
Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure but try to console.log(e) and console.log(value) in your onChange function. this might give you some hints

Comment: I have console.log but this doesnt help me at all, i think i just need to clear the field with empty string or something i dont know

Comment: can you share your esportTeams.list ?

Comment: it's a private things sorry but it's a action api call with a object array and on that i got a id, nama and logo

Answer (score 4):

**EXPLANATION:**

If you deeply think about the error, when you press the X button inside the Autocomplete component it triggers the onChange event because it changes the value to null

```
onChange={(e, value) => setFilter({ ...filter, team: value.name })}
```

Objects are complex data structures. The simplest object in JavaScript is the plain object — a collection of keys and associated values:

```
let myObject = {
  companyName: 'Exploretale Technologies, OPC'
};
```

There are situations when an object cannot be created. For such cases, JavaScript provides a special value null — which indicates a missing object.

```
let myObject = null;
```

"null is a primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value."

That's why you're having this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')"

**SOLUTION:**

```
onChange={(e, value) => 
if(value === null) {
 //Just give a value to a value to avoid null
 //e.g. value = ""
}
setFilter({ ...filter, team: value.name })}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your esportTeams.list should be an array of strings or numbers. It doesn't accept objects, your value is selected item in the input. So you can't look for a property on that.

I think you intended to do this;

```
onChange={(e, value) => setFilter({ ...filter, team: value })}
```

Comment: Ok now its works when i click but the value.name help me to display what i want in the website, if i remove "name", the video not appear on the site and esportTeams it's a action api call, i take the "list" of the video in a object array and i display these videos with value.name